# Intermittent issue with accessing page - DXA

Tags: dxa

When trying to access a page (DXA), we are intermittently seeing the below error.

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Internal Server Error ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.GetMatchingConverter(IList`1 converters, Type objectType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.GetConverter(JsonContract contract, JsonConverter memberConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract,
>
> JsonProperty containerProperty)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](JsonReader reader)
>      at DD4T.Serialization.JSONSerializerService.Deserialize[T](String input)
>      at DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.GetIPageObject(String pageStringContent)
>      at DD4T.Factories.PageFactory.TryFindPage(String url, IPage& page)
>      at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultProvider.GetPage(String url, Localization localization)
>      at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultProvider.GetPageModel(String url, Localization localization, Boolean addIncludes)
>      at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.PageController.Page(String pageUrl)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>      at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be an issue in DD4T: https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.Core/issues/100

The issue seems to happen on IIS app pool restart. A pragmatic work-around is to ensure that the app pool doesn't restart that often.

Comment: May be you can try updating your NuGet Package, which claims that they have resolved the issue https://www.nuget.org/packages/DD4T.Model/2.2.1.46-alpha